# Функция с переменным количеством аргументов

Tags: c#

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в C# определить функцию, которая принимает переменное количество аргументов.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
void Func(DateTime firstParam, params object[] parameters)
```

Потом внутри функции можно работать с переданным массивом параметров как с обычным массивом. Перед массивом параметров может быть любое число фиксированных параметров, массив параметров всегда последний

Answer (score 2):

Герберт  Шилдт - C# 4.0. Полное руководство - 2011
Глава 8. Подробнее о методах и классах 229

Использование переменного числа аргументов

```
public int MinVal(params int[] nums) 
{
  ...
```

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/216780)

Comment: @lDrakonl, в принципе содержится.

Comment: @Qwertiy в этом ответе присутствует отсылка к книге и кусочек кода без малейших объяснений того, что это и как оно работает. Например я знаю C# лишь поверхностно и мне совершенно не понятен такой ответ. Считаю, что такой ответ не является самодостаточным, так как требует дополнительных вопросов или загугливания, о чем и поставил отметку из очереди проверок.